# Running a Java/Selenium program on another computer

Tags: java, selenium, launch4j

I have a small Java program that uses Selenium that I'd like to install on someone else's computer so they can use it too. It uses Selenium (for what it's worth).

I exported from Eclipse to a jar file. I then used launch4j to create a windows executable. I used Java version 1.7_079 to develop the program.

The other computer has JRE version 1.7_079 installed I made sure CLASSPATH is set.

If I run this executable on my system it works fine. If I try and run it on another system nothing happens at all, no errors, no nothing.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Would it be easier to NOT wrap it in an executable and just use a batch file to run it?
3. what's the best and easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: try running `java -jar myApp.jar` in console.

Comment: I would double check to make sure any web drivers you're using are included as well on the other persons machine

Comment: I found a couple things. 1. The other system needs chrome driver installed  on it. 2. The references to chrome driver need to be non-explicit. I'll keep this updated as I go.

Comment: I solved one part of it. Another question, I thought when you exported from Eclipse that it packaged any required jar files with it. Is this not true?

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the .jar directly on the system where it doesn't work by using java.exe/javaw.exe and note the error, if any.

java.exe -jar helloworld.jar

If you get "'java.exe' is not recognized..." you need to add the folder where java/w.exe is to your path (eg: SET PATH=folder-with-java-exes;%PATH%

You can locate java/w.exe files with:

cd /d c:\

dir /S java*.exe

Comment: It can't find the libraries. It's trying to maximize chrome and cannot. I thought when you export from eclipse and say package the jars that it would do that but apparently it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have an answer to this. I traced it down to an issue with Chrome and Chrome driver. I was running Chrome v55.0.x. The users computer was running 57.0.*. Once I upgraded my machine to 57.* it failed like the users did. I updated Chrome driver and everything works as expected.

Answer (score -2):

you can try this in your code put the path as C:/xxxxxxxx.exe
and put  selenuim and the web driver In the C drive and create a jre or exe now .
next step is to ask your client to put selenuim and the web driver also in the C drive in there computers and int will work fine .